Function with memories of its past life
Task
I need a function that accept string and return a function f1.
That f1 function should also accept string and return a f2 function, but as a side effect it must print string passed to previous function.
That f2 function should also accept string and return a f3 function, but as a side effect it must print string passed to previous function.
And so on.
For language that require explicit declaration of side effects (like haskell) you may return next best thing (like IO(...) in haskell).
For language that don't have function as first class object (like Java) you may return next best thing (like instance of Function interface in Java).
You need to show function and example of it usage.
This is code golf all standard rules apply. Only function itself is counted in score. Example is for demonstration only.
Reference implementation in Java
    static Function<String, Function> f(String s) {
        class C implements Function<String, Function> {
            String s1;

            public C(String s) {
                s1 = s;
            }

            @Override
            public Function apply(String s) {
                System.out.println(s1);
                return new C(s);
            }
        }
        return new C(s);
    }

Example of usage
        Function<String, Function> t = f("s1");
        t = t.apply("s2"); // Prints "s1"
        t = t.apply("s3"); // Prints "s2"


if f1 returns a new function f2, how is the function remember "its" past life. :(

@tsh You right. This question doesn't make sense. I'll remove it.

Can we print to stderr instead of stdout?

@bzr Yes. I think it is part of standard rules.

JavaScript (V8), 21 bytes
f=s=>x=>f(x,print(s))

Try it online!

This is way simpler than my Java solution.

By looking at the code, I haven't noticed that it prints before running it myself. I love this.

K (ngn/k), 9 bytes
partial application ftw
{ \x;o@y}

Try it online!
 f:{ \x;o@y}
 f:f"s1"
 f:f"s2"
"s1"
 f:f"s3"
"s2"


R, 24 bytes
f=\(s)\(t){show(s);f(t)}

Attempt This Online!

Java, 85 bytes
interface N{N f(String s);static N i=s->t->{System.out.println(s);return N.i.f(t);};}

Try it online.
Explanation:
interface N{     // Interface to use as our lambda
  N f(String s); //  taking a String parameter, and returning another instance of itself

  static         // Static context so we're able to reference the interface
         N i=    // Create this interface as re-usable lambda method:
    s->          //  Taking a String parameter and returning another lambda method:
       t->{      //   Also taking a String parameter and returning a lambda method:
         System.out.println(s);
                 //    Print the String of the outer lambda with trailing newline
         return  //    And then return
           N.i.f(t);};}
                 //     A call to the outer lambda with the inner String parameter,
                 //     using a static call to prevent 'self-reference in initializer' errors


Why don't you put i inside N. This way you don't need to depend on outer class name. Which look little bit sketchy.

And you missed ; at the end of definition of i.

@talex You're completely right about putting it inside the interface, fixed. (As for the missing ;, those usually aren't counted with pure lambda answers, hence why I put it at the end. But when it's used within the interface, it's indeed required.)

"usually aren't counted with pure lambda answer" I allow it. Java need every bit of advantage in those contests :)

Arturo, 33 bytes
f:$->x->$.import:->x=>[f&print,x]

Try it!
Ungolfed:
f: function [x][
    function .import:[x] [y][
        print x
        f y
    ]
]


Ruby, 23 bytes
f=->s{->z{puts s;f[z]}}

Try it online!

C (gcc), 27 bytes
t;f(s){t&&puts(t);t=s;s=f;}

Try it online!

I smell something shady :) You aren't returning function that print previous result. If I call returned function again I will get different result. That was same function all along. C don't play by the rules, I guess :)

@talex It is very shady, but I think it does what the OP wanted.

Yes. OP allows it :) I never explicitly required the function to work more than once. Is it common loophole? If not you may want to mention it in your answer.

Just to satisfy my curiosity: I know that C functions always returns something, even without return, but why it returns pointer to itself?

@talex, see this

that's so cool dude

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 19 18 bytes
f@a_=f[Print@a;#]&

Try it online!

(subjectively) more interesting:
24 bytes:
Curry[Print@@##2;#0]@!#&

Try it online!
27 bytes:
#0@*(D@@(#/._?Print@_->$))&

Try it online!

Haskell, 57, 45 bytes
Solution using a constructor:
data U=U([Char]->IO U);f s=U$(<$putStrLn s).f

Try it online!
Invalid solution using typeclasses:
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances#-}
class F a where g::String->a
instance F()where g _=()
instance F a=>F(String->IO a)where g a b=g b<$putStrLn a

Try it online!
The the typeclass based version will eventually return IO (), so it isn't really infinite. The non-typeclass based version however does go on forever.

Two function for a price of one is bargain :) I doubt it even possible to do it with one function because type of such function will be infinite.

@talex I found a solution using type classes that only uses 1 function if FlexibleInstances is enabled. Is my previous solution still acceptable given that this is possible? Try it online!

You can have both solution in your answer. Explain the difference between them. It would be fair to score proper solution though.

PARI/GP, 21 bytes
f(x)=t->print(x);f(t)

Attempt This Online!

Python 3, 38 bytes
f=lambda x:lambda y:[f(y),print(x)][0]

Try it online!
Well sadly, the anonymous function can’t be shorter while being completely anonymous… ‍

37 bytes.

35 bytes: f=lambda x:lambda y:print(x)or f(y)

C++, 69 bytes
auto f(auto s){return[=](this auto t,auto n){return cout<<s,s=n,t;};}

Try it online!

Clojure, 25 bytes
defn f[s]#(do(pr s)(f %))

Try it online!

Rust, 57 49 45 29 bytes
fn x(s:&str)->!{dbg!(s);x(s)}

Attempt This Online!
